# How to calculate $x\%$ chance of success?

Tags: probability

Everything I've looked for points to Binomial Distribution, but I have no idea how to use it.

Basically, I have $2$ sets of $7$ rolls. Each roll has a specific chance of success.

Set 1:
$$5.3\%,\quad 8.6\%,\quad 8.1\%,\quad 3.3\%,\quad 3.8\%,\quad 13\%,\quad 10.3\%$$

Set 2:
$$0\%,\quad1.2\%,\quad 4.3\%,\quad 9.5\%,\quad 6.4\%,\quad 0\%,\quad 9.5\%$$

In the actual data I'm calculating I have $6$ sets of $7$ percentages. I need to find out how many success would happen within all $6$ sets. I also would like to know what the success count max-min would be for 'rolling' the percentages in a random generator $1000$ times.

Comment: Obviously when there is a random element, we do not "find out how many success would happen" except by actually trying the experiment.  Perhaps you are interested in the *expected value* of the number of successes in a certain number of repetitions, but you confuse matters further by asking "to know what the success count max-min would be".

Comment: Given the seven chances in set 1, is the chance of success in the set the total of them all?  The chance that at least one succeeds? The total number of successes?  Or what?  Please clarify.

Comment: @hardmath The min-max isn't so important. Though I would be interested in know how to find it. You mentioned I must _try the experiment_ how does one do that? I'm not sure what _expected value_ means. Does that give the average number of successes?

Comment: @RossMillikan Each number is rolled separately so the chance of success is individualized and not totaled as a set. So I'm looking for a total number of successes.

Comment: In set 1 you do seven rolls with each one having one of the listed percentage chances of success.  Is Set 1 defined as a success if at least one of the seven succeeds?  Do you care whether more than one succeeds?  You make $42$ total rolls.  Are you asking about the total number of successes in those $42$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Sets aren't defined successful by 1 or more successes. I do want to know the number of successes in a set whether *0* - *7*.

Comment: You could succeed (or fail) in all the trials, so it isn't clear what "the success count min-max would be for rolling... 1000 times" except to say zero to 1000.  Yes, the expected value is the average number (of successes).  The binomial distribution allows you to calculate the expected value (easy) or to compute the probability of getting a certain number of successes.

Answer (score 1):

For your set 1, the chance of no success is $(1-0.053)(1-0.086)(1-0.081)(1-0.033)(1-0.038)(1-0.13)(1-0.103)\approx 0.57746$  The chance of one success is $0.053(1-0.086)(1-0.081)(1-0.033)(1-0.038)(1-0.13)(1-0.103)+0.086(1-0.053)(1-0.081)(1-0.033)(1-0.038)(1-0.13)(1-0.103)+0.081(1-0.053)(1-0.086)(1-0.033)(1-0.038)(1-0.13)(1-0.103)+\dots$
With no regularity that I can see in your percentages, you are in for a fair amount of computation.  To get the chance of two successes, you evaluate the chance of each pair by multiplying the individual chances and the chance the other five fail.